# Вопрос по определению функций в структурах

Tags: c++, структуры

В С++, как я понял, можно прямо в структуру впихнуть ф-цию. До этого я кодил на Си, в котором так сделать нельзя (разве что через указатель на ф-цию) и у меня появился такой вопрос: насколько такой подход эффективен? Всмысле: не выделяется ли при этом больше памяти на каждую структуру? Если у меня две структуры с идентичными переменными, хранящихся в них, но при этом в одной определены ф-ции, а во второй ф-ции вынесены из структуры - будет ли в первом случае расходоваться больше памяти? Почему?

Comment: Не будет, функции не хранятся в структуре.

Comment: Общий ответ - нет, больше памяти расходоваться не будет. Структуры в данном случае будут оперировать сходно с классами, и все функции структуры будут неявно получать указатель `this` для доступа к конкретному объекту. По факту `void func(struct mystruct *data)` будет идентично функции `struct mystruct { void func(); }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На размер класса может повлиять появление в нем *виртуальных* функций (если раньше в нем виртуальных функций не было), ибо в такой ситуации в объектах класса будут храниться скрытые данные, необходимые для реализации виртуальных вызовов. Влияние на размер объектов класса в "традиционной" реализации не зависит от количества виртуальных функций.

В остальном методы класса на размер класса в "традиционной" реализации никак не влияют.

Comment: Я думаю, тут стоит добавить про общие отличия структур от классов, т.к. ТС спрашивал про структуры. Default `public` vs `private`.

Comment: @Ternvein Формально в С++ нет никаких "структур" - есть только классы. А отличия эти к теме вопроса никак не относятся.

Comment: Если перечитать вопрос, то ясно видно, что для ТС это неочевидно. Возможно, про виртуальные функции классов он и так знал, а вот про то, что структуры почти во всем аналогичны классам - нет.

Comment: действительно не знал, так как не знаком (пока) с С++ - до этого, как я писал, кодил на Си, где нет никаких классов.